# the purpose of function parameters with two indirection operators (C++)

Tags: c++, function, parameters

What is the purpose of a function parameter that has two indirection operators? 
Since a call by reference is changing the value of the original variable I thought that a function parameter with two indirection operators might change the address of the original value.
But as my attemp below shows, it does not:

```
void addrchanger(int**);

int main()
{
    int value1 = 4;
    int* value1ptr = &value1;
    std::cout<<&value1<<std::endl;

    addrchanger(&value1ptr);
    std::cout<<&value1<<std::endl;
    //the address of value1 doesn't change.
}

void addrchanger(int** foo)
{
    //this is an attempt to change the address of value1 to the next slot
    ++**foo;
}
```

Comment: It changes your value1. Use cout << value1 instead of &value1.

Comment: You can't change the address of anything, ever. Once something is created, it stays in the same place until it doesn't exist any more.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose is to pass a pointer to pointer(s) or a pointer to array(s). Such practise is C-like for historical functions like main() `char** argv` (that is why you also want an argc, because the size cannot be deduced by the pointer). It is also used when you want to be returned a pointer, so you pass a pointer to a pointer, like in many Win32 functions.

For example in [StringFromIID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-stringfromiid)

```
HRESULT StringFromIID(
  REFIID   rclsid,
  LPOLESTR *lplpsz
);
```

you would pass a double pointer as the 2nd parameter (a `wchar_t**`) in order to be returned a pointer, which them must be deallocated like the doc says.

Avoid that *completely* nowadays in C++ and use std::vector in whatever depth is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The `void addrchanger(int** foo)` function can change:

- the value: `(**foo)++` making `int value1` to 5
- and address: `(*foo)++` making `value1ptr` point to the next space after `value1`

I believe you expected the `++**foo` to move `value1` to the next position, which is not the case.

The pointer to pointer is also useful for matrix declarations, but most libraries such as the GNU scientific library, BLAS, OpenGL `glLoadMatrixf()`, prefer the use of a single pointer.

Answer (score 0):

When `p` is of type `int **`,

```
++**p
```

increases the value of the int represented by `**p`.

In order to change the address of the int pointed to, you would use

```
++*p
```

With direct access to your variable, you would use one `*` less for everything:

```
int *p;
++*p; // increment the int value
++p; // increment the pointer
```

But inside such a function, every arguments is just a copy, so if you want to change something outside, you need a pointer to it, which means that one more `*` is used for everything.

```
function f(int **p) {
  ++**p; // increment the int value
  ++*p; // increment the pointer
  // you can also increment the argument
  // but you can't know whether it will then
  // still point to another int pointer:
  ++p
}
```

In addition, you can use & instead of * in C++ which is used only for declaring a variable as a reference and then works like a secret, hidden pointer. You use one less `*` again, like outside the function at the beginning.

```
function f(int *&p) {
  ++*p; // increment the int value
  ++p; // increment the pointer
  // you can also not increment the reference itself,
  // as it is a hidden pointer.
}
```

This sounds dangerous because who would want secret pointers? But it is very common in C++ because people like typing less `*` all over the place.